# Fixing differently sized characters with Carlito font

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I am trying to write a document with LuaTex and want to use the "Carlito" font. For this, i use the *fontspec* package and then simply set the main font to *Carlito* as shown in the example below. However, i noticed that the number 8 is differently sized than other numbers, which looks weird in the final pdf. I added an example output down below. The difference is especially noticeable when comparing the numbers 8 and 9.

I also tried to use the *carlito* package with identical results when adding the *lf* option. Without *lf*, the results are even worse.

**Question**: Is there a way to make the numbers of the Carlito font all the same size?

**Example**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Carlito}
% \usepackage[sfdefault, lf]{carlito} % even worse when not using lf
\begin{document}

\section{My Test Section}

Normal Text

1234567890
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image: Output of the latex document with the character "8" being of different size]

Comment: Sorry, but that's how the digits are designed to appear.

Comment: If you don't like the design of the Carlito numbers, you could use a different font for the numbers. Carlito looks like a fairly generic sans serif font, it should be possible to find a similar font for the numbers, so they'll blend in.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I guess it makes sense that this can't be changed, i was just a bit confused because the Carlito font is metric-compatible with Calibri, which doesn't have this issue.

Comment: If you scale the  Calibri font by 1.031 they will look identical or vice versa, depending on how you mixing the fonts.

Comment: Carlito IMHO is in the wrong here. It also differs from Lato, compare 1 and 8. Also if you use MS fonts Segoe UI, has a better range of Unicode chars.